# Combine SimpleBar + Drawer (MaterialUI) in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to have a simple bar in which I will put a logo, and below, a drawer. The problem is when I open the drawer, the simple bar moves with it. Besides, I can see the logo text is hidden by drawer.

I've tried to add zIndex to the simpleBar but it doesn't work. I'm really not familiar with react and material ui so don't see how to fix my problem.

Here's my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/sharp-browser-lsolr?fontsize=14 , if anyone can help.

I'm sorry, when clicking on my codesandbox, you'll see an error I don't get 'cause my code comes from material-ui and I don't see what the problem is.. Just click on the cross to close it. 
Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you need the additional AppBar to display the logo, or can you just use the app bar that comes with the mini variant drawer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-matsumoto-c84r8

The SimpleAppBar component was removed, and the MiniDrawer component which already has an AppBar has been modified so that everything looks right and you can put your logo where you want it.

Comment: Thanks but I really need to keep the simple bar. It's like I need a fixed header, which doesn't move with the drawer. Maybe that's not possible, I don't know

Comment: You may not be using an appropriate drawer type if you need a persistent drawer. The drawer type that you have selected will always push the entire page contents to the right (or left, depending on which side the drawer is on). I would suggest looking into [Temporary Drawers](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#temporary-drawer)